# Como passar valores javascript para C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Possuo uma classe Cliente, onde um cliente pode ter varios beneficiarios como podem ver na ultima propriedade.

```
public class Cliente
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Id
        /// </summary>
        public long Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// CEP
        /// </summary>
        public string CEP { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cidade
        /// </summary>
        public string Cidade { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// E-mail
        /// </summary>
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Estado
        /// </summary>
        public string Estado { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Logradouro
        /// </summary>
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nacionalidade
        /// </summary>
        public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome
        /// </summary>
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sobrenome
        /// </summary>
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Telefone
        /// </summary>
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cpf
        /// </summary>
        public string Cpf { get; set; }

        public List<Beneficiario> Beneficiarios { get; set; }
    }
```

Classe Beneficiario:

```
public class Beneficiario
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Id
        /// </summary>
        public long Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cpf
        /// </summary>
        public string CpfBeneficiario { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome
        /// </summary>
        public string NomeBeneficiario { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Id do Cliete
        /// </summary>
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }

    }
```

Código JS:

```
    var rowIndex = -1;
var beneficiarios = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formCadastro').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lista = document.getElementById('tbLista').rows;    
        for (var i = 1; i < lista.length; i++) {
            beneficiarios.push(JSON.stringify({ "cpf": lista[i].cells[0].innerHTML, "nome": lista[i].cells[1].innerHTML }));
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPost,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "NOME": $(this).find("#Nome").val(),
                "CEP": $(this).find("#CEP").val(),
                "Email": $(this).find("#Email").val(),
                "Sobrenome": $(this).find("#Sobrenome").val(),
                "Nacionalidade": $(this).find("#Nacionalidade").val(),
                "Estado": $(this).find("#Estado").val(),
                "Cidade": $(this).find("#Cidade").val(),
                "Logradouro": $(this).find("#Logradouro").val(),
                "Telefone": $(this).find("#Telefone").val(),
                "Cpf": $(this).find("#Cpf").val(),
                "Beneficiarios": JSON.stringify(beneficiarios)
            },
            error:
                function (r) {
                    if (r.status == 400)
                        ModalDialog("Ocorreu um erro", r.responseJSON);
                    else if (r.status == 500)
                        ModalDialog("Ocorreu um erro", "Ocorreu um erro interno no servidor.");
                },
            success:
                function (r) {
                    ModalDialog("Sucesso!", r)
                    $("#formCadastro")[0].reset();
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Alterar(ClienteModel model)
        {
            BoCliente bo = new BoCliente();

            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<string> erros = (from item in ModelState.Values
                                      from error in item.Errors
                                      select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();

                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return Json(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, erros));
            }
            else
            {
                var cpf = RemoverCaracteresEspeciais(model.Cpf);
                var existeCPF = bo.VerificarExistencia(cpf);
                if (existeCPF)
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 400;
                    return Json("O Cpf já está cadastrado.");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Validacoes.ValidaCpf(cpf))
                    {
                        bo.Alterar(new Cliente()
                        {
                            Id = model.Id,
                            CEP = model.CEP,
                            Cidade = model.Cidade,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            Estado = model.Estado,
                            Logradouro = model.Logradouro,
                            Nacionalidade = model.Nacionalidade,
                            Nome = model.Nome,
                            Sobrenome = model.Sobrenome,
                            Telefone = model.Telefone,
                            Cpf = cpf
                        });

                        return Json("Cadastro alterado com sucesso");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = 400;

                        return Json(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, "O cpf digitado é inválido."));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Tenho uma tabela onde adiciono Cpf e nome de cada beneficiario para aquele respectivo cliente, consigo passar todos os dados para minha controller porem nao tenho ideia de como seria para passar os valores da tabela tb. Minha duvida é essa, como posso passar valores de uma tabela no front end via ajax para minha lista de beneficiarios da classe Cliente no c#?

Comment: Você quer saber como passar alguma informação de uma tabela "Front End" para a controller "Back End"?

Qual seria a informação?

Pode mostrar o código HTML?

Comment: isso mesmo, ao chegar no back end que é c# a lista está vindo zerada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer o parse corretamente, você deve colocar o mesmo nome nos atributos (Model/View).

Esta linha: `beneficiarios.push(JSON.stringify({ "cpf": lista[i].cells[0].innerHTML, "nome": lista[i].cells[1].innerHTML }));`

deveria ficar assim: `beneficiarios.push(JSON.stringify({ "CpfBeneficiario": lista[i].cells[0].innerHTML, "NomeBeneficiario": lista[i].cells[1].innerHTML }));`

Comment: Isso eram os nomes mesmo obrigado.