# Como atribuir um valor vindo do Javascript para uma função de um Servico em C#?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Atualização: o problema aqui discorrido é bem específico do meu projeto. Mas deixarei aqui pois tem uma dica: se precisar acessar dados do banco pelo JavaScript, use o Fetch -> https://www.devmedia.com.br/javascript-fetch/41206

Preciso selecionar uma Cidade em um SelectList e, a partir dessa Cidade filtrar os Portos correspondentes a mesma.

```
 <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
     <label class="control-label">Cidade</label>
     <select id="MunicipioId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(servico.GetMunicipio().Result, "Id", "Nome"))">
         <option value="">Selecione aqui</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2 ">
     <label asp-for="PortoId" class="control-label">Porto</label>
     <select id="IdPorto" asp-for="PortoId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(servico.GetPorto().Result, "Id", "Nome"))">
         <option value="">Selecione aqui</option>
     </select>
 </div
```

Tenho que passar o Id do Municipio para a função GetPorto(int id), essa função vem de um Serviço, que chama os dados do servidor:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Porto>> GetPorto(int id)
 {
     return await _context.GetAll<Porto>().Where(c => c.MunicipioId == id).OrderBy(c => c.Nome).ToListAsync();
 }
```

Mas não consigo passar o valor do JavaScript para o método c#.

```
<script>
    $('#MunicipioId').on('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var idMunicipio = $('#MunicipioId').val();       
    })
</script>
```

O id tinha que ser atribuído neste trecho:
[Trecho do html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ui7.png)

É possível fazer essa atribuição?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como passar valores javascript para C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/404054/como-passar-valores-javascript-para-c)

Comment: Infelizmente não.. o problema é apenas passar o valor para a função GetPorto() que chamo no html, não sei se é possível passar uma variável do js no html com c#. Pelo o que testei ela só existe dentro do <script>

Comment: @RicardoPontual saberia me dizer se isso possível?

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes sobre a estrutura do seu projeto? tenho a impressão que seu método GetPorto esta acessando dados do servidor. não seria viável fazer uma requisição http para isso?

Comment: @MarcosJunior É de uma aplicação da empresa que trabalho, já existe uma, essa eu criei do zero e estou atualizando para as tecnologias atuais .net. Os dados vêm do servidor mesmo. Essa função fica num serviço, é o padrão que usamos pra obter listas de objetos pra chamar nos SelectList do html, e funciona. Na minha pouca experiência (e não tendo noção de http) não vejo o porquê e nem como chamar assim.

Comment: Suponho que seja uma aplicação aspnet mvc, a maneira como voce esta querendo fazer não vai funcionar. Isso porque todo o código c# é renderizado no servidor e após ser enviado para o navegador, não teria como ser chamado esse código sem que seja feito uma requisição http. o código javascript será executado quando estiver rodando no navegador e não no servidor.

Comment: entendi Marcos! é asp.net mvc mesmo. muito obrigada pela ajuda! consegui de uma forma aqui, vou responder

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver com a ajuda de uma função JS que eu já tinha, que utiliza o fetch: https://www.devmedia.com.br/javascript-fetch/41206

(Trata-se de uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC)

Código JS que percebe a mudança do idMunicipio:

```
$(function () {

    token = $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    $('#MunicipioId').on('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;

        var idMunicipio = $('#MunicipioId').val();
        const url = urlBase + `DadosDesembarque/GetPorto/${idMunicipio}`;
        const options = { method: 'get' };

        var portos = '<option value="">Selecione aqui...</option>';
        $('#IdPorto').html(''); /* acessando o DOM */

        debugger;
        Update(url, options).then((response) => {
            if (idMunicipio !== '') {
                $(response).each(function (i, porto) {
                    portos += "<option value='" + porto.id + "'>" + porto.nome + "</option>";
                });

                $('#IdPorto').html(portos);
            }
            else {
                $('#PortoId').html(portos);
            }
        })
        .catch( error );
    });    
});
```

A constante `url` recebe o endereço do método passando o idMunicipio, dessa forma: `NomeController/Action/${parametroId}`

A constante `options` indica um método apenas de GET.

Código da função Update com Fetch:

```
async function Update(url, options) {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    debugger;
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    else {
        throw new Error(`Erro ao realizar a requisição, Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
};
```

O Fetch realiza uma requisição para a Action no Controller.

O método para buscar os dados no servidor que antes estava em um serviço, coloquei no Controller dessa forma:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPorto(int id)
 {
     var result = await _context.GetAll<Porto>().Where(c => c.MunicipioId == id).ToListAsync();
     return Ok(result);
 }
```

O result retorna para o Update, que por sua vez retorna um `response`, com o status positivo igual a "ok", e converte o resultado para JSON. Após isso, retorna o response para a function JQuery (primeiro código).

Através do `each()` eu percorro os resultados do JSON e atribuo os valores `porto.id` e `porto.nome` para a variável que é enviada para o DOM.

O HTML fica assim:

```
 <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <label class="control-label">Cidade</label>
    <select id="MunicipioId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(servico.GetMunicipio().Result, "Id", "Nome"))">
        <option value="">Selecione aqui</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2 ">
    <label asp-for="PortoId" class="control-label">Porto</label>
    <select id="IdPorto" asp-for="PortoId" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione aqui</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PortoId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

No final, está funcionando perfeitamente.